# Ubuntu 12.10 in Wubi boots fine, but GRUB does not show

Tags: installation, grub2, windows, 12.10, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit) directly from the Windows installer. When I start up and select Ubuntu from the Windows boot manager, it correctly passes the command to GRUB, but the GRUB menu does not display - all I see is a blank purple screen. After about 10-15 seconds, the sign-in screen shows up (which means it booted fine).

Is there any way to force it to show the GRUB menu?

Comment: Disabling the graphical screen (setting "GRUB_TERMINAL=console" in /etc/default/grub) does not work.

Comment: Does holding down **Shift** after Windows boot manager show GRUB? Please edit your original question rather than enter new information in comments like the comment above.

Comment: When you are using wubi, It is not necessary that Grub should be open.

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of /etc/default/grub?

Answer (score 1):

The grub menu is hidden by default for Wubi installs (on Vista/7, not XP). The reason is that it's not required when the only two OSes are Windows and a Wubi-installed Ubuntu, and it has led to some problems when users assumed they could boot Windows from Grub, when in fact you can't.

If you run `sudo update-grub` you'll see something like this:

```
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
```

This means that grub considers it to be a single OS situation, and therefore defaults to hiding the Grub menu.

If you want it to show, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting *Ubuntu* from the *Windows boot manager*, or change the settings in `/etc/default/grub` but I'd have to ask why you want to do this.